# Getting json data into table in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

The returned json response data from http post is the following:

```
{"ResponseData":[["AUSTRALIA","VICTORIA","MELBOURNE"],["AUSTRALIA ","NEW SOUTH WALES","SYDNEY"]]}
```

Controller code:

```
app.controller('tableController', function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.customerTable = [];
        $scope.getTable = function ()
        {
            $http.get('getTable.do').success(function (data)
            {
                $scope.customerTable = data;
            });
        };
    });
```

Here is my div:

```
<div ng-controller="tableController">
    <p>    Click <a ng-click="getTable()">here</a> to load data.</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>COUNTRIES</th>
            <th>STATES</th>
            <th>CITIES</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in customerTable">
            <td>{{data[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{data[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{data[2]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I use ng-repeat to load the data its just displaying it as {{data.country}} rather than actual value. There's no server side problem as I am getting response back but unable to understand why data is not displayed in the table?

Comment: Are you using any other frameworks? Such as Symfony which by default uses the same brackets for expressions -> `{{expr}}`.

Comment: No I am not using other frameworkds

Comment: I talked about this in the other question you asked earlier today. ```$http.get``` is sending an asynchronous request which apparently has not been completed by the time the code is compiled. ```$scope.customerTable``` is empty, use ```console.log($scope.customerTable)``` at the end of your controller to verify.

Comment: You're trying to plot `data.country`, `data.state` and `data.city` but you don't handle any kind of objects with those properties (eg, obj = { country: 'Australia', state: 'Victoria', city: 'Melbourne' }). You only have an array of arrays. Maybe you should consider redesign the response so you won't need to iterate over an array of arrays and then assign each index from an inner array being the `country`, the `state` and the `city` in this order.

Comment: Look at your response data structure.  Where is there a key called country, state or city?

Comment: @jme11 Updated the question and changed it to `data[0]` but still not working

Comment: @Avalanche then how do I call it after code is compiled?

Comment: @kittu can you try once, I updated my answer

Comment: @Avalanche I think only registered directive will be called for compile function where as I am using controller function in my case

Comment: Your controller function doesn't have `$http` as parameter.

Comment: @kittu You did change your view structure, but you didn't change your controller (at least not in the question).  As is pointed out in both answers below, you need to add the ResponseData array into your customerTable -- not the entire object that is returned.

Comment: fixed my problem with this: `$http.get('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GetTable.do').success(function (data)`

Comment: Strange but without `<%=request.getContextPath()%>` it is just calling servlet name rather than calling webappname+servletname

Comment: @kittu An advice - working with JavaScript for web requires you to have the developer console opened all the time. The cool thing about AngularJS is that it is always telling you what is wrong with your code and suggests what might fix it. So, you should always keep an eye at the log and always dump your variables by using ```console.log``` to easily track possible issues within your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
Controller:-

```
app.controller('tableController', function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.customerTable = [];
        $scope.getTable = function ()
        {
            $http.get('getTable.do').success(function (data)
            {
                $scope.customerTable = data["ResponseData"];
            });
        };
    });
```

html:-

```
<div ng-controller="tableController">
            <p>    Click <a ng-click="getTable()">here</a> to load data.</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>COUNTRIES</th>
                    <th>STATES</th>
                    <th>CITIES</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in customerTable">
                    <td>{{data[0]}}</td>
                    <td>{{data[1]}}</td>
                    <td>{{data[2]}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>1
```

Comment: Tried this `$scope.customerTable = data["ResponseData"];` still not working

Comment: Avalanche has pointed something about asynchronous call and code compilation. I am still new to angular. I think only registered directive will be called for compile function where as I am using controller in my case

Comment: yeah as per him, try putting `console.log($scope.customerTable);` before the controller ends. Have you verified?

Comment: add `console.log(data)` before ` $scope.customerTable = data;` inside `$hhtp()` in controller . Can you please tell what it logs.. that would be helpful

Comment: Thanks @Sudhansu. Fixed it finally. commented it above

Comment: cool.. nice! I figured out now that you didn't have `$http` injected in your controller :D didn't notice that. Actually I know you have solved it but can you check if `$http.get('/getTable.do')` would work instead of `$http.get('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GetTable.do')`. I guess it should. It would be sleek. Just in case you time to try this :)

Comment: Yes I forgot the injection. I tried with the slash but it didn't work

Comment: hey but the answer was fine as per the data provided. Wasn't it? :)

Comment: One more question coming up. Will provide a link if you are interested ;)

Comment: Here's the link for new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121949/pagination-in-angular-js

Answer (score 3):

```
{"ResponseData":
     [
         ["AUSTRALIA","VICTORIA","MELBOURNE"],
         ["AUSTRALIA ","NEW SOUTH WALES","SYDNEY"]]
}
```

Its an object which contains array ResponseData, which contains two arrays with 3 strings. You should do this:

```
app.controller('tableController', function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.customerTable = [];
        $scope.getTable = function ()
        {
            $http.get('getTable.do').success(function (data)
            {
                $scope.customerTable = data.ResponseData;
            });
        };
    });
```

And HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="tableController">
    <p>    Click <a ng-click="getTable()">here</a> to load data.</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>COUNTRIES</th>
            <th>STATES</th>
            <th>CITIES</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in customerTable">
            <td>{{data[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{data[1]}}</td>
            <td>{{data[2]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```