# Pagination in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the data from database via http post call and rendering the table. Well the implementation code looks fine however, the pagination doesn't seem to work.

I implemented it according to my requirement and I get the response which I can see in chrome console. What could be wrong with the pagination as I am not able to see any pagination buttons.

Here's the code:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <base href="/">
            <title>The Single Page Blogger</title>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.12.1" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/module.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style2.css" />
            <script>

                //Get table from Server and do pagination
                app.controller("tableController", function ($scope, $http) {
                    $scope.filteredTodos = []
                            , $scope.currentPage = 1
                            , $scope.numPerPage = 10
                            , $scope.maxSize = 5;

                    $scope.getTable = function () {
                        $scope.customerTable = [];

                        $http.get('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GetTable.do').success(function (data)
                        {
                            $scope.customerTable = data;
                        });
                    };
                    $scope.getTable();

                    $scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function () {
                        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                                , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                        $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.customerTable.slice(begin, end);
                    });
                });

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container" id="main"><br/><br/>
                Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search">
                <div ng-controller="tableController">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Card number</th>
                            <th style="font-size: 13.3px">First name</th>
                            <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Opening balance</th>
                            <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Withdrawal</th>
                            <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Deposit</th>
                            <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Closing balance</th>
                            <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Tx date</th>
                            <th style="font-size: 13.3px">Usage type</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="data in customerTable| filter: search">
                            <td>{{data.CARD_NUMBER}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.FIRST_NAME}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.OPENING_BALANCE}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.WITHDRAWAL}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.DEPOSIT}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.CLOSING_BAL}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.TXDATE}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.USAGE_TYPE}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <pagination 
                        ng-model="currentPage"
                        total-items="customerTable.length"
                        max-size="maxSize"  
                        boundary-links="true">
                    </pagination>
                    <br/><br/><br>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eNgT4bVroGIla4EOdkNZ?p=preview

Module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: I can see the pagination and everything seems to work fine

Comment: Yes its not working with my code. The plunker is just a demo

Comment: Do you have `['ui.bootstrap']` defined as a dependency injected? As in like, `var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);` ??

Comment: I can't see the `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js`script in your code, did you check you have everything like the plunker?

Comment: Yes just now I added it and tried but still didnt work

Comment: Do you have ['ui.bootstrap'] defined as a dependency injected?

Comment: yes its injected. updating the question...

Comment: my bad. I used wrong injection into controller rather than module. Its working now but unable to move into next page. All the items are displayed in one page

Comment: I have about 25 rows and all are displayed on single page

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
                <tr ng-repeat="data in filteredTodos| filter: search">
                            <td>{{data.CARD_NUMBER}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.FIRST_NAME}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.OPENING_BALANCE}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.WITHDRAWAL}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.DEPOSIT}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.CLOSING_BAL}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.TXDATE}}</td>
                            <td>{{data.USAGE_TYPE}}</td>
                        </tr>
```

You should be iterating `filteredTodos` instead of `customerTable`

Comment: Unable to get response data on the view when I use filteredTodos

Comment: I can see the response in chrome console but using filteredTodos table is empty

Comment: You should be iterating over filteredTodos only, thats how it should be.. However, add a `console.log(data)` after `$scope.customerTable = data;` inside the `$http.get()` call and share that please

Comment: Strange its working with filteredTodos but its loading table data only after I click on any of the page numbers

Comment: So you mean the first page is blank?? Ok let me check. Show the data please. That would be of great help! :)

Comment: first page is not blank. Its loading data only after I click on page number

Comment: <%=request.getContextPath()%> is getting root folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81895/discussion-between-sudhansu-choudhary-and-kittu).

Comment: looks to me as a case of the view not been updated. 
I mean, the other logic of pagination is getting doe with before you http call finishes. 
that's how it is acting.
So, when you click the button or take any action, the view gets updated with values because now you will have data ready which was fetched from $http.get() call

Comment: It's not supposed to work like that. Data should be loaded readily for user to interact

Comment: Thats not the case always, yes it should but if you make it to be! For example, `$http.get()` sends an asynchronous call to the server, while the call is fetching data, the rest of the code would compile, hence sometimes you dont get the data ready in hand as the page loads. This is one amongst the various reasons why people use promises, $q s etc.

Comment: In your case you have a lot of dynamic compilation to be made, it's not only AngularJS part that is getting compiled but also, the CSS and js that you have imported on top seem to take some time as the path provided is getting compiled with respect to the Context using `<%=request.getContextPath()%>` I would suggest you to load these using relative paths.

Comment: @kittu found something for you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369377/how-to-use-http-get-in-angularjs-correctly-in-specific-for-an-external-api-cal

Comment: `angular.module('mainApp', []).controller('MainController',
['$scope','$q','$interval',function($scope, $q, $interval)` Any idea why scope,q and interval are getting injected twice in this piece of code?